# Javascript (or similar) gaming scripts for C# XNA

Tags: c#, javascript, xna

Lately I am preparing myself to develop yet another game in XNA C#.

The last time I worked on a game in XNA C#, I ran into this problem of having to add maps and customizable data into the game. Each time I want to add in new content or change some values to the game character or something, I had to rebuild the whole game or what - which can take quite some time.

Is there any way which I can write gaming scripts to load the content that can be interpreted by my XNA C# game without having to compile? I am looking at hopefully Javascript.

I would hope that I can add in functions and other small API which can be called from the external gaming script to manipulate the game or load data so on. I am not concerned about the game being hacked since it's quite early yet - the development is of much priority.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at Lua? It seems to be a useful language for scripts.

Comment: I have definitely looked at Lua. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com) which is a open source Javascript interpreter written in C#

Comment: this looks like a very cool and easy idea. But how can I define pre-defined functions that can be called to run certain C# methods for example?

Comment: Ah ok I think Jint supports that as well, as written on http://jint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Old question, I know, but this is exactly what I did just recently and it works really well, I was even able to create some debugging functionality. Here's some code (free to use ofc) : http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2012/06/05/using-javascript-as-a-script-engine-in-xnac/

Answer (score 2):

The compact framework doesn't include System.Reflection.Emit, which means you can't use IronPython. I recommend LUA, and you can find an XNA interpreter implementation with open source [here](http://www.xnua.com/xna_lua_xnua)

Comment: it looks good. but I can't get it working on Visual C# 2008. The project seems to be very old.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with getting it to compile, he offers precompiled binaries - just add a reference in your game to the dll.

Answer (score 1):

Would IronPython be more appropriate? That should work well on "full" framework - but it looks like it might [not work (yet) on xbox 360](http://www.itags.org/msdn/1830363/) (which uses compact framework).

For an IronPython / xna example, [see here](http://paste.lisp.org/display/24997).