# How to use jint with XNA to build a game engine?

Tags: c#, xna, jint

I want to create a game engine in XNA that has scripting abilities (Jint). How do I go about doing this? (General idea of the direction to proceed - not necessarrily deatils).

Thanks

Q

Comment: Is this not a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988767/jint-xna-c (which was also asked by you)?

Comment: Hi. I dont know what the mods would say - but this is slightly different to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

It's really just as you say, you make your game engine, in C#. You embed Jint and expose the relevant parts of your game engine to it, and provide a way for clients of your game engine to register scripts that run in response to game events or whatever you have planned.

If you are more specific about where you lack direction, you may get more specific direction from people here :)

Not to spoil your fun here, but if you had to ask this question, maybe you should consider a less ambitious project, like building Jint support into an existing XNA game engine? That would give you much better odds of getting something more concrete than just a learning experience out of this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know I can do this but just needed to make things clearer.