# Using a C Sharp file as a script file

Tags: c#, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read the properties of a C# class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-dynamically)

Basically, I would like to be able to write a script file (in C# syntax) but then read this into an application so the application will execute the contents of the file.

I don't want the script file to contain the namespaces etc. but the script file will be straight forward C#.  For example a script file might look like:

```
if (Balance == 0 && Withdrawal > 0)
{
    // Don't allow this to happen
}
```

Basically, like Business Rules but in a script format.

Any ideas or references that I could look at?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832293/c-scripting-language) for information about C# scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

In an application I implemented sucessfully scripting by using the C# compiler and dynamically using the generated code.

You can specify the references to use during compilation and compile one or several files "on-the-fly". You get also the warnings/errors on compilation.

This should be done in a clean fashion with AppDomains but here are a few starters.

- [Executing code dynamically in C#](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm)
- [Scripting with C#](http://www.vsj.co.uk/dotnet/display.asp?id=417)

A more complex way to use scripting is demonstrated in this "game" where also the security aspects are solved correctly along with the use of AppDomain:

- [AntMe! Webpage](http://antme.net/)
- [AntMe! source code for VS2010](http://antme.net/antme_source_vs2010.zip)

The only aspects I am struggling with are:

- Debugging of the script
- If you want to keep it simple, how to find an easy GUI for the script snippets